# Is $\rm\det (A+B) = \det (A) + \det (B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a general rule for the determinant of the sum if we know the determinants? For example:

If $\rm \det A = 1$ and $\rm\det B = 2$ and there is $ \rm A+B$, is $\rm\det (A+B) = \det (A) + \det (B) = 3$ ? Thank you.

Comment: No${{{{{{}}}}}}$.

Comment: This can be easily broken with $2\times 2$ examples like the identity matrix and the matrix full of ones.

Comment: If you don't want to mess with specific examples, think about that if the statement was correct, then it would follow that: $2\det(A) = \det(A) + \det(A) = \det(A + A) = \det(2A) = 2^n\det(A)$, and for $n>1$ you get a contradiction

Comment: You might be interested in the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329972/relationships-between-detab-and-ab

Comment: You should have used Google for this question.

Answer (score 3):

For a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $a_{11},\cdots, a_{nn}$, the determinant is the product of said entries. So, even in easy cases such as $A$ and $B$ being both diagonal, there is less of a correlation between $\det A$, $\det B$ and $\det (A+B)$ than there is between the product of $n$ numbers, the product of other $n$ numbers and the product of their sums (in some order).

Answer (score 3):

is there a general rule for the determinant of the sum if we know the determinants?

No.

Counterexample of `if det A = 1 and det B = 2 and there is A+B, is det (A+B) = det (A) + det (B) = 3 ?`

Let $A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1\\
   0 & 1\\
  \end{array} } \right]$
and $B=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2 & 0\\
   2 & 1\\
  \end{array} } \right]$, then $\det A=1$ and $\det B=2$

Now $A+B=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   3 & 1\\
   2 & 2\\
  \end{array} } \right]$, then $\det (A+B)=4\neq \det A+\det B$