# What's the proof of this $\det(A+B)$ identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Assume $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and let $M$ denote the set of $2^n$ matrices we get by replacing, in turn, each subset of columns of $A$ with the corresponding columns of $B$.  Then $$\det(A+B) = \sum_{C \in M}\det(C).$$

---

I found this result on a [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/330252/961906), but neither was it named nor was any proof provided.  Since I can't find the name or proof anywhere, I ask the question here. What is this formula called?  What is its proof?

Comment: **Hint :** The determinant is multilinear w.r.t. the columns.

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?  I assumed it was a quote. Please let me know if I assumed incorrectly.

Comment: Of course, there is a similar identity where one instead replaces some rows of $A$ with the corresponding rows of $B$. Also, one could instead replace some columns (or rows) of $B$ with the corresponding columns (or rows) of $A$.