# If $ \det\left(A+X\right)=\det\left(B+X\right) $ for any $ X $ then $ A=B $

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $ A,B \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F}) $ be matrices such

$ \det\left(A+X\right)=\det\left(B+X\right) $ for any $ X\in M_{n\times n}\left(\mathbb{F}\right) $.

Prove that $ A=B $.

My idea is to assume by contradiction that $ A \neq B $ and therefore we can find $ X $ such that $ \det\left(A+X\right)\neq\det\left(B+X\right) $. But this is just intuitive idea, I dont know how to find this $ X $ in order to prove the what I claim.

I'll be glad for some help with finding such $ X $ that would satisfy the idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove/disprove: if $\det(A+X) = \det(B + X)$ for all $X$, then $A=B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383748/prove-disprove-if-detax-detb-x-for-all-x-then-a-b)

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383748/prove-disprove-if-detax-detb-x-for-all-x-then-a-b